# Copying the 3D view Framebuffer doesn't give me the current frame. Bug or expected behavior?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu-module

I'm writing an addon for which I need to extract information out of a cycles viewport render.
In essence, I'm using a callback function in the [SpaceView3D](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add) that gets called every time the 3D viewport is drawn. I then cache the Image information and wait until the viewport stops beeing drawn. Then i save the current cache into an image. My understanding is that the image schould be identical to the viewport result, but some frames are saved twice and others are missing completly.

Here is my example code and i will add a blendfile to the question.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel
import gpu
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
import traceback

def saveImage(self, drawcall):
    if not self.end:
        time.sleep(self.frametime.microseconds/1000000*10)
        try:
            if drawcall == self.drawcalls:
                self.pixelBuffer.dimensions = self.width * self.height * 4

                #saving image
                name = "image"+str(self.drawcount)
                image = bpy.data.images.get(name)
                if image == None:
                    image = bpy.data.images.new(name=name, width=32, height=32, alpha=False, float_buffer=True)
                image.scale(self.width, self.height)
                image.pixels.foreach_set(self.pixelBuffer)
                print("saved ", drawcall)
                
                #advancing drawcount and camera
                self.drawcount += 1
                cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
                cam.location.x+=2

                
                if self.drawcount >= 10:
                    self.end = True
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()


def callback(self, context):
    self.drawcalls += 1
    
    #save the time between frames
    if self.drawcalls == 1:
        self.frametime = datetime.now()
    if self.drawcalls == 2:
        self.frametime = datetime.now() - self.frametime

    # get currently bound framebuffer
    self.framebuffer = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()

    # get information on current viewport 
    self.viewport_info = gpu.state.viewport_get()
    self.width = self.viewport_info[2]
    self.height = self.viewport_info[3]
    
    print("reading ", self.drawcalls)
    #caching curent framebuffer content
    self.pixelBuffer = self.framebuffer.read_color(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')

    if self.drawcalls >= 2:
        thread = threading.Thread(target = saveImage,args=[self, self.drawcalls])
        thread.start()

    return



class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_description = ""

    def __init__(self):
        print("Start example code")
        self._handle_3d = None
        self.drawcalls = 0
        self.drawcount = 0
        self.firstRun = True
        self.end = False
        self.frametime = 0
        
        self.spaceView3D = None
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for space in area.spaces:
                    if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        self.spaceView3D = space
        self.spaceView3D.shading.type = 'RENDERED'



    def execute(self, context):
        print("here")
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if self.firstRun:
            self.firstRun = False
            self._handle_3d = self.spaceView3D.draw_handler_add(callback, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW')
            cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
            cam.location.x = 0
            if(bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective != 'CAMERA'):
                bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera()
                bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera()
            
            
            
            
        
        if event.type in {'ESC'} or self.end:
            self.spaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle_3d, 'WINDOW')
            self.spaceView3D.shading.type = 'SOLID'
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera()
            print("Removing draw handler")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("Invoking modal operator")

        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
class CB_PT_Panel2(Panel):
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.operator(ModalOperator.bl_idname)
        
bpy.utils.register_class(CB_PT_Panel2)
bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
```

[image]